# AWS Cognito Users + Relational Database Table. How to query/integrate both?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-cognito

I'm new to AWS and I really need help with this. I have an existing RDS Schema with Users table and also with my own Users authentication algorithm/system using JWT. Everything was fine until I reached working on uploading files to S3. I discovered that when uploading to S3. We cannot pass extra parameters but only the body, key, contentType and to which bucket. I wanted to pass extra parameters like the current logged in user's access token (for user validation security), user_id, photo title and caption. But it's not possible.

What should I do? Should I use AWS Cognito User Pools instead of using an RDS Users? If I use Cognito User Pools, is it possible to do a SQL Query like joing a Cognito User and another RDS Table? I'm so confused. I'm sorry if I sound like an idiot. But I really need some help about this.

I hope somebody can. I would really appreciate it. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your upload logic is in Lambda. In this case you can just do your authorization for the upload in the Lambda function. Allow the Lambda function to upload data to S3 by attaching an IAM policy to the IAM role that Lambda uses.

If you upload to S3 directly from a client, then you can either do that without authentication/authorization or use Federated Identities. In this case you can either export all your users to a Cognito User Pool (and keep them in sync) OR create your own Identity Provider and register your users for a Cognito Identity Pool.

The cleanest, but probably also hardest, way is to keep your authentication,  integrate with the Cognito Identity Pool via OpenID, SAML or your own method (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html).

You should go that way only if a) your authentication is really good and b) you have verified that having the user in a Cognito Identity Pool actually meets your requirements/business rules.